# ASP.NET : Method not found when calling for parent class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, litedb

basically I'm getting an exception while im performing this:

```
var userDb = new UserData();
userDb.InsertData(DbName);
```

My InsertData function:

```
var userRepo = new UserRepository();
var users = new List<User>();
using (var db = userRepo.InitialDb(dbName))
{
    userRepo.AddList(_users);

    users = userRepo.GetAll();
}
```

and while I'm running InsertData function, i get this exception:

> {"Method not found: 'LiteDB.LiteDatabase Db.Data.Repository.Repository`1.InitialDb(System.String)'."}

My UserRepository.cs

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>{}
```

While my Repository.cs:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> where T : class
{
  protected LiteDatabase db;

  public LiteDatabase InitialDb(string dbPath)
  {
      db = new LiteDatabase(dbPath);
      return db;
  }
}
```

So the question here is,

**1. I don't know if i inherited my parent well.**

**2. If yes, why there is a method not found exception thrown?**

Thanks in advance, let me know if i missed out anything in the question.

Comment: Can be a problem with LiteDB versions. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578583/method-not-found-on-runtime and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly caused by the version of LiteDb, thank you.